# Installing Tensor Flow

Tags: macos, tensorflow, machine-learning, terminal, tensorflow2.0

I am trying to install tensor flow on mac and have gotten up to the install package step on this page: https://www.tensorflow.org/install/source#macos
When I run that line with the version switched I get this error.

`[ERROR: tensorflow-2.1.0.whl is not a valid wheel filename.][1]`

If anyone could help me I would really appreciate it. I m not sure if it is because I did the previous steps wrong or I am doing something wrong on this step.
Thanks

Comment: Is there a reason you are installing from source? Can you install using the `pip` package? https://www.tensorflow.org/install/pip#2.-create-a-virtual-environment-recommended

Answer (score 0):

Seems like you are following the instructions for the Docker Linux builds for MacOS, not plain MacOS.

If you plan on using MacOS try

```
pip3 install tensorflow
```

I also started learning machine learning on MacOS with Nvida 650M 1.5gb but quickly found out that it wasn't ideal.
For very basic examples you'll get by with doing AI on MacOS but I strongly recommend you switch to a desktop with dedicated gpu. (gtx 1660 or rtx 2070) are great options. I also recommend getting Ubuntu.

Comment: I tried that and got this error. I also tried running the pip install and got this. https://imgur.com/a/F3SqtKf

Comment: try 

    pip3 install --upgrade pip